# SwiftUI Combine synchronously execute codes

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift, combine

I call an API and perform some actions based on the response.

```
let test = apiPublisher
    .subscribe(...)
    .receive(...)
    .share()

test
    .sink {
        //do task1
    }.store(...)

test
    .sink {
        //do task2
    }.store(...)

test
    .sink {
        //do task3
    }.store(...)
```

Now how can I execute the task1, task2, task3 one after another. I know I can have all the code in one sink block. For code readability I'm using the `share()` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Code put in sinks need to be independent. If you want them to depend on each other (one should not start until the other finishes) then you can't put them in sinks.

You will have to put each task in its own Publisher. That way the system will know when each is finished and you can concat them.

```
test.task1
    .append(test.task2)
    .append(test.task3)
    .sink { }
    .store(...)
```

I'm assuming that each task needs something from `test` in order to perform its side effect. Also each task needs to emit a Void event before completing.